# Change Indentation Size in algorithmicx package

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm using and enjoying the `algorithmicx` package, but would like to adjust the size of its indentations.

In the `algorithms` package, I could do this with `\algsetup{indent=1em}`, but that doesn't seem to work here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can renew the internal command `\algorithmicindent`:

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{2.0em}%
```

Change the `2.0em` to whatever you wish.

Here is a MWE extracted from the documentation and adapted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpascal}
\usepackage{algc}
\newcommand{\euk}{Euclid}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{2.0em}%
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hskip3em$\rightarrow$ #1}
\State $x\gets x+1$\Comment{Here is the new comment}
\end{algorithmic}
\alglanguage{pseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{\euk's algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{\euk}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
   \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
   \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
   \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
   \State \Return $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```